# In Android 11 R, Camera REQUEST_CODE returns zero

Tags: android-camera-intent, android-11

I am trying to take image and save it in a folder using camera intent. The code is working very fine in other Android versions (upto Android 10). But the same code is not running on Android 11. I am also recording video using Custom video camera, but it is working fine in Android 11 also. Please help me with the same.

Camera code :-

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                                // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
                                                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                                                    File photoFile = null;
                                                    try {
                                                        photoFile = Utilites.createImageFile(photocount, getActivity());
                                                        
                                                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                                                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Catched No Directory",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                                                    if (photoFile != null) {
                                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                                            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                                                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                                                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
                                                        } else {
                                                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                                                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                                                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
                                                        }
                                                    } else {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Directry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Take pic intent null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
```

The Utility class code where the image file is created. The folder name for saving images is based on the number generated from server.

```
public static File createImageFile(int id, Activity activity) throws IOException {
        String mCurrentPhotoPath;
        // Create an image file name
        String imageFileName = "";       
        File storageDir = new File(activity.getFilesDir() + "/Photos/" + Job_Inspections_Activity.LeadID + "/Pictures/");
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            storageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        String directory = storageDir.toString();
        for (int i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
            Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            String ts = tsLong.toString();
            File file = new File(directory + "/" + ts + "-" + i + "~Photo.jpg");
            if (file.exists()) {
                // do nothing
                // as the image already exists and if we do anything it might override it
                //so leave this condition as it is.
            } else {
                // if the given file name is not found then pass the first name that is encountered and do not exists.
                // and then break the loop as it useless to continue to do so.
                imageFileName = ts + "-" + i + "~Photo.jpg";
                break;
            }
        }

        File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
        /*File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  *//* prefix *//*
                ".jpg",         *//* suffix *//*
                storageDir      *//* directory *//*
        );*/

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

I have checked in device explorer of the emulator, it is showing the files created, using above method, but camera always returns 0 (zero) in result code.

My module level build.gradle file info

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 29
```

I am also not getting any warning/error messages in Logcat.

I have tried many solutions for this problem, but none of them worked.

Comment: You should have been crashing for years with a `FileUriExposedException`, as `Uri.forFile()` has effectively been banned since Android 7.0. You may have some hack code to disable that exception via `StrictMode`. If so, please remove it. Then, switch to `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` method to get your `Uri`. See [this older sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Camera/FileProvider) for how to use `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Yes Sir, you are right about the StrictMode. But the reason I was using this is that the folder name is generated dynamically, as per the number recieved from server. Meanwhile I implement FILEPROVIDER, as suggested by you, can you please tell me if I can use FILEPROVIDER for dynamic folder name ? The path is created as "/com.myapp.package/Photos/121212/Pictures". The number in the middle of the path is recieved from server.

Comment: You would configure `FileProvider` to serve `Photos/`, which will include all subdirectories with all numbers.

Comment: Thank You @CommonsWare Sir. The issue got resolved. If anyone gets stuck due to this issue, plese refer the solution in the comment.